# Changing SVG image attributes by button click using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have created one svg door image using Adobe illustrator.The image has 3 components

1. Door body
2. Glass part in center of the door
3. Door handle. >>

[image]

I want change the this 3 attributes by clicking buttons like changing handle, color, body material etc.
I have open this svg file in dreamweaver and it's looking weird with long image links and codes. 
I don't know where to start with.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version:  6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0  0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect x="146.889" y="134.444" fill="#6B4520" stroke="#000000" stroke-   miterlimit="10" width="328.889" height="487.777"/>
<path fill="#BDE5F1" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M372.998,351.667c0,38.2-25.577,67-66.998,67
c-41.421,0-71.002-28.8-71.002-67c0-38.2,27.579-64.667,69-  64.667C345.419,287,372.998,313.467,372.998,351.667z"/>
 <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="155.665"    y1="352.25" x2="174.25" y2="352.25">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#603913"/>
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
  <stop  offset="0.0161" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
  <stop  offset="0.3333" style="stop-color:#D9CDC0"/>
  <stop  offset="0.5161" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
  <stop  offset="0.8763" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"  points="171.333,430.556 164.958,434 159.111,430.556 
155.665,344.667 159.111,272.778 164.958,270.5 171.333,272.778 174.25,344.25  "/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: I don't know about DreamWeaver dealing with SVG but you can add to your question the `SVG`s code [from Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html) and we could help you to handle this.

Comment: Thanks Mosh..I am using illustrator cs6. in export option there is no .svg format, but I can Save As svg file format.The svg format we can edit the styles,fill color etc but in my case the code looks very big.

Comment: It's make sense because your image contains many elements. You can create a [bin](http://jsbin.com) with all your code and we help you. Just keep it mind to group the elements you want to replace like handle etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonably simple, the most important part is you include the `svg` within the `html` not simply as an image `src` attribute. The following is not dreamweaver specific.

For example:

```
<body>
   <!-- this won't work well -->
   <img src="/images/door.svg>
    ...
   <!-- this will work very well -->
    <svg>
        <path></path>
        <path></path>
    </svg>
    ...
</body>
```

Now just like any other element you can give the `svg` and `path` elements `id`'s and `classes`

```
<svg id="door">
    <path id="handle"></path>
    <path id="window"></path>
</svg>
```

From here you can use event listeners to those specific elements for example (with jQuery) to run off other functions for the customization of these `svg` elements.

```
$('#handle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('fill', 'blue') // change path fill to blue
})
```

`path`'s and other `svg` elements can more or less be styled with css which makes this a lot easier.

This isn't a copy and paste answer, but I hope it helps you!

Comment: Yes Brod .This is what im a lookin for.now it has more clarity, I have som more qstion over that,In svg format can we have separate control over each elemnts? let me clear       <svg id="door">
                                         <path id="handle"></path> 
                                         <path id="window"></path>
</svg> here can I filter out each element ? since it is exported as a single svg image? thanks a lot brod.

Comment: I like this solution +1. I would not user jquery with svg, in my expirience there are a lot of cases where they will not work together.

Comment: @Tony, `svg` files generally look something like the code I wrote in the answer (although with a lot more information) - try opening the `svg` file up within a text/code editor, dreamweaver might be doing something strange which prevents you from seeing the code.

Comment: @Persijn yeah, I'm not a fan of using jQuery for everything and anything but it's much easier to read visually, but I've also never had an issue with jQuery and svg's - it's just like any other dom content

Comment: My SVG code is attached please have a look and check how inline editing is possible with this stuff.